# aggregate in mongodb with a tuple

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with many informations and I want to retrieve only distinct origin and destination. I used this script :

```
   dbcollection.aggregate( 
                [
                    {"$group": { "_id": {origin: "$origin", destination: "$destination" } } }
                ]
            );
```

I get this :

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "origin" : "QJZ",
        "destination" : "CGQ"
    }
}
```

I want to get only a document with origin and destination like this (tuple of origin and destination):

```
{

        "origin" : "QJZ",
        "destination" : "CGQ"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to your pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { "_id": { "origin": "$origin", "destination": "$destination" } } },
    { "$project": { "origin": "$_id.origin", "destination": "$_id.destination", "_id": 0 } }
]);
```